# Javascript version of list.pop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create a javascript version of python's pop function.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
function pop(arr, idx) {
  arr = arr.splice(0, idx).concat(arr.splice(idx + 1));
  console.log(arr);
}
```

I am not sure of why it is only returning the first part and not combining with the second.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop

Comment: `splice()` returns an array of all the deleted elements. When you don't pass the second parameter, nothing is deleted, hence `arr.splice(idx + 1)` deletes nothing and returns an empty array. Conversely `arr.splice(0, idx)` deletes `idx` amount of items starting at position `0`. JS already has [`Array#pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) by the way.

Comment: I voted the question down because I don't know what you're calling it with or what you expect to get out of it; those are all array functions and are described explicitly, I think you just need to debug it a bit, break out the inline statements if the chain is broken

Comment: Not to be confused with [JavaScript's array pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop), which removes the last element.

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for something like this? maybe you can modify it so that the pop function returns the removed element.

```js
const arr1 =  [10,20,30,40,50,60];
const arr2 =  [10,20,30,40,50,60];
const arr3 =  [10,20,30,40,50,60];

function pop(arr, idx) {
    removedEl = arr.splice(idx,1)[0];
  console.log('removed element: ',removedEl)
  console.log('final array: ',arr);
}

pop(arr1,0);
pop(arr2,2);
pop(arr3,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.splice()` modifies the array. It doesn't create a new array. All you need is this:

```
const pythonPop = ( arr , i = -1 ) => arr.splice(i,1)[0];
```